# Does the Ripple simulator support Tizen Enyo projects?

Tags: tizen, ripple, enyo, tizen-web-simulator

We are creating a Tizen Enyo app and would like to test on the Apache Ripple simulator in the browser. I do not see any support for the Tizen or Enyo platforms in Ripple. Does the Ripple simulator support Tizen Enyo projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use Ripple and not [Websimulator](https://01.org/web-simulator/)? Websimulator supports Tizen API and is built over Ripple.

I don't see any reason you cannot use Enyo in the widget application like any other JavaScript  framework file, just define the following in `index.html` to load the `enyo.js` library.

```
<script src="enyo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I was using Ripple because that it what I had been using for other projects. I did not know about Web Simulator from Intel, but will give it a try.

Comment: I have been using the Tizen 2.2 Web Simulator for days now and it works very well. I had originally expected the Ripple Chrome plugin to support Tizen, but the Web Simulator is just as good. The simulated GPS works well too. Thanks for the tip.